# Nginx rewrite rule with variable

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to send all request that came from a sub-domain to index.php and send subdomain name as a `$sub`

for example:

```
sub1.mydomain.com
send the above request to:
/var/www/mydomain/index.php?sub=sub1
```

what I've tried:

```
rewrite ^(\w+).mydomain.com /index.php?sub=$1 last;
root /var/www/mydomain/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites are done in the request URI. This does not contain the host name. Assign the variable `sub` a default, then using an id statement capture the subdomain replacing the default. Then use an unconditional rewrite.

```
$sub=www;
if($host ~ ^(\w+\.example.com$) {
    $sub = $1;
}
rewrite ^.*$ /index.php?sub=$sub$args;
```

From the top of my head. Tweak it using the relevant documentation.